# trait `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` is not implemented for `unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>`

Tags: parachain, frontier, cumulus

I was trying adding Frontier as a dependency to my parachain project...

After fixing a few errors and adding UncheckedExtrinsic & CheckedExtrinsic:

```
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic =
    fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, SignedExtra>;
pub type CheckedExtrinsic = fp_self_contained::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId, Call, SignedExtra, H160>;
```

I got this error during compilation:

```
➜  substrate-parachain-template-evm git:(polkadot-v0.9.25) ✗ cargo build -r
   Compiling parachain-template-runtime v0.1.0 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/runtime)
   Compiling fp-self-contained v1.0.0-dev (https://github.com/PAIDNetwork/frontier?branch=patch3-polkadot-v0.9.25#2e4daa4e)
   Compiling pallet-transaction-payment v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.25#3348e144)
   Compiling frame-election-provider-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.25#3348e144)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>: parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` is not satisfied
    --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-b733f450c86c5786/2e4daa4/primitives/self-contained/src/unchecked_extrinsic.rs:71:75
     |
71   | impl<Address, Call: SelfContainedCall, Signature, Extra: SignedExtension> Extrinsic
     |                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` is not implemented for `unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf`:
               &'a T
               ()
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1)
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2)
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3)
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4)
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5)
               (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5, TupleElement6)
             and 113 others
note: required by a bound in `Extrinsic`
    --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:1129:30
     |
1129 | pub trait Extrinsic: Sized + MaybeMallocSizeOf {
     |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Extrinsic`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>: parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-b733f450c86c5786/2e4daa4/primitives/self-contained/src/unchecked_extrinsic.rs:142:58
    |
142 | impl<Address, Call: SelfContainedCall, Signature, Extra> ExtrinsicCall
    |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` is not implemented for `unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf`:
              &'a T
              ()
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5, TupleElement6)
            and 113 others
note: required by a bound in `ExtrinsicCall`
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/frame/support/src/traits/misc.rs:673:26
    |
673 | pub trait ExtrinsicCall: sp_runtime::traits::Extrinsic {
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `ExtrinsicCall`
```

I have don't know what is missing in my code.
This `parity_util_mem::malloc_size::MallocSizeOf` has never appeared in my code...
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `patch`.

If the traits' versions mismatch. You will get this error.

For example:

```
# crate_a Cargo.toml
scale-info = 2.0

// crate_a lib.rs
#[derive(TypeInfo)]
pub struct S;

---

# crate_b Cargo.toml
scale-info = 1.0
// crate_b lib.rs
pub trait T: TypeInfo { fn f(); }

<crate_a::S as T>::f();
```

The compiler will say `S` did not implement `TypeInfo`.

Comment: Yes, after removing the patched dependency URL and use the real ones instead, it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Remember the "default-features = false" https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/cannot-find-macro-vec-in-this-scope/4164#4164